# What URL do I use to send users to google oauth2 consent screen

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-authentication, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to write a simple application to access google's api using user authentication tokens and html requests, however I am struggling to find what URL I send users too in order for them to select a profile and sign in.

Comment: Are you using the google APIs .Net client library?  If so are you doing this in asp .net core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> URL I send users too in order for them to select a profile and sign in.

The thing is you are confusing authorization and authentication.  Oauth2 a user can authorize you to access their data, it has nothing to do with logging in to your application that's OpenID connect.

However what you are probably looking for is the  oauth2 consent screen  This is the screen where the user consents to your application accessing their data.

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id={clientid}&redirect_uri={redirectURI}&scope={scope}&response_type=code
```

Remember this is only the first step if they consent then you will be given an authorization code your application must then exchange the authorization code for an access token which you can use to access the api.

You may find this video helpful in understanding the fill Oauth2 dance. [Understanding Google OAuth 2.0 with curl](https://youtu.be/hBC_tVJIx5w)

If you are looking to login a user and check their profile something like this would be better

```
[GoogleScopedAuthorize(PeopleServiceService.ScopeConstants.UserinfoProfile)]
 public async Task UserProfile([FromServices] IGoogleAuthProvider auth)
        {
            var cred = await auth.GetCredentialAsync();
            var service = new PeopleServiceService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = cred
                });
            

            var request = service.People.Get("people/me");
            request.PersonFields = "names";
            var person = await request.ExecuteAsync();

            return View(person);
        }
```

The full tutorial and companion video can be found here [Asp .net core 3 and Google login](https://www.daimto.com/asp-net-core-3-and-google-login/)